# Can you have complete coverage when using the pure component pattern to test Gatsby's static queries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, gatsby

According to [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/testing-components-with-graphql/#testing-staticquery), components that use static queries need to be split into variants: one being a pure component and the other that actually uses the static query, passing results to the pure component.

Given an example component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

export const PureSEO = ({
  description = ``,
  lang = `en`,
  meta = [],
  title = ``,
  image = ``,
  ...metaData
}): JSX.Element => {
  const metaDescription = description;

  return (
    <Helmet
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang,
      }}
      title={title}
      titleTemplate={`%s | ${title}`}
      meta={[
        {
          name: `description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          property: `og:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:type`,
          content: `website`,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:card`,
          content: `summary`,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:creator`,
          content: metaData.author,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          name: `og:image`,
          content: image,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:image`,
          content: image,
        },
        {
          name: `image`,
          content: image,
        },
      ].concat(meta)}
    />
  );
};

const SEO: React.FC<Props> = ({
  description = ``,
  lang = `en`,
  meta = [],
  title = ``,
}): JSX.Element => {
  const { site, image } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author
            rootDir
          }
        }
        image: file(relativePath: { eq: "favicon.png" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fixed(width: 400) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );

  return (
    <PureSEO
      {...site.siteMetadata}
      description={description}
      image={image}
      lang={lang}
      meta={meta}
      title={title}
    />
  );
};

interface Props {
  description?: string;
  lang?: string;
  meta?: HTMLMetaElement[];
  title: string;
}

export default SEO;
```

I don't get full test coverage because `SEO` is not tested; but I don't think I *should* be testing that component, since the only logical difference is that it is using static queries.

**How can I achieve better or 100% test coverage for my components, given this pattern?**

Comment: Update: This question inspired me to write [a Gatsby plugin that allows unit testing](https://github.com/ehrencrona/gatsby-plugin-testing) of GraphQL components. It does this by storing the query data when you run `gatsby build` and the exposing it to your tests so you can run the unmodified component and receive the same GraphQL data as during the build.

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

I understand the intention of the Gatsby documentation avoid executing useStaticQuery, but the approach implicitly recommends leaving code uncovered.

## Recommendation

To achieve code coverage, the most logical thing to do would be to either mock `useStaticQuery` or better yet use [`MockProvider`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#mockedprovider).

GraphQL Testing: MockProvider - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#mockedprovider

Comment: I get that. If you read the link I provided, you are expected to separate the static query from the component (but still keep it in a component, since it needs to be rendered), and test only the pure component. That leaves me wondering about the default export. Your answer doesn't address that

Comment: @Martin I missed that part. Thanks for clarifying, I've updated my post :-). I'll also open a PR to update documentation to recommend the more idiosyncratic approach to mocking GraphQL providers.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is quite similar to how you would do unit testing of a backend component that communicates with some kind of external service, such as an SQL database.

You could of course mock `useStaticQuery` which will give you higher coverage, but it will not actually make you any surer that your code will work. What you want to test revolves around the correctness of your GraphQL query and whether the response format is what you expect, which is not something you can unit test.

So if you want to be certain that your code works you'd need to perform integration testing, e.g. by running [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) tests against the built website.

Theoretically, you could also use [contract testing](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ContractTest.html) to check that your query itself performs as expected, but it seems like an unnecessarily complicated solution for this usecase.